# Click on an anchor not working

Tags: javascript, callback, tinymce

I am trying to click on an anchor, but it shows type error .. not a function.

**here is my code:**

```
file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
    win.document.getElementById("media").onclick();     
    win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = 'window.send_to_editor'; 
},
```

**Why I am doing this**

I am using Tinymce editor, and I want to use `file_browser_callback`.

There is an anchor `#media` in my document which open a Thickbox and after selecting an image in thick box it send a callback `send_to_editor`,

So I want to get the value from `send_to_editor` and set to

```
win.document.getElementById(field_name).value
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: win.document.getElementById(...).onclick is not a function
```

Please dont suggest jQuery code, I need pure javascript (tinymce init dont support jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an event has been bound with `addEventListener`, running `onclick()` won't work (as it will still be `null`)

You could try the following:

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
clickEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                          false, false, false, false, 0, null);

document.getElementById('media').dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```